# Results of SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a SQL query to know the number of times that the same value is on a column.

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(CustomerID) AS OrdersFromCustomerID7 
FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerID=7;
```

Query Result:

```
OrdersFromCustomerID7
---------------------
4
```

Since I want to put the "4" value to a Linux Environment Variable, I would need to remove the `OrdersFromCustomerID7` text from the result. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Note: I have already tried removing the `AS OrdersFromCustomerID7` from the query and that makes the query result to come like below:

```
COUNT(CustomerID)
-----------------
4
```

I need the query result to be returned as a single number since this is afterwards put into an environment variable for future analysis by another script.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Use a database connector.

Comment: which dbms you are using?

Comment: You need to set the property to disable the header. Like in Oracle `set heading off`

Comment: @spencer7593: sql is not dbms mate, SQL server, MySQL, Oracle etc are dbms. sql is just language.

Comment: @Ambrish any ideas how to implement the 'set heading off' in the above code I posted? Thanks.

Comment: @Gonzalo, Are you using Oracle? If yes, then when you open the sqlplus you can just execute above command as is and then execute you regular SQL statements.

Comment: @Ambrish I am using SQL Server.

Comment: @Gonzalo, Can you try `SQLCMD -q "SQL STATEMENT" -h-1`.

Comment: @Ambrish I get ERROR 1064 (42000) (Wrong syntax). Thanks

Comment: @Ambrish I was finally able to get it working with this: mysql "DATABASE" -N -s -r "SQL STATEMENT" // Thanks a ton for your time!

Comment: @Gonzalo this is msql not SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get it to work using the following modifiers in the query:

```
mysql "DATABASE" -N -s -r "SQL STATEMENT"

-N removes headers
-s removes separator chars
-r raw output
```

Thank you @Ambrish for your time!